# How to change SpotLight shadowCameraNear parameter in THREE.js?

Tags: dynamic, three.js, shadow, spotlight

How do I change the shadowCameraNear and shadowCameraFar parameters of SpotLight?

In this demo, I change the `shadowCameraNear` parameter in the animation loop, but even though console.log() shows the change happened, the shadowCameraVisible helper object shows no change.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Angrypickle/3h8h1pzd/20/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the pattern you need to follow if you want to change a light's `shadowCamera` parameters dynamically.

```
light.shadowCameraNear += 0.01;

light.shadowCamera.near = light.shadowCameraNear;

light.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix(); // important
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3h8h1pzd/21/

three.js r.69